# What's the best way to split a string into fixed length chunks and work with them in Python?

Tags: python

I am reading in a line from a text file using:

```
   file = urllib2.urlopen("http://192.168.100.17/test.txt").read().splitlines()
```

and outputting it to an LCD display, which is 16 characters wide, in a telnetlib.write command.  In the event that the line read is longer than 16 characters I want to break it down into sections of 16 character long strings and push each section out after a certain delay (e.g. 10 seconds), once complete the code should move onto the next line of the input file and continue.

I've tried searching various solutions and reading up on itertools etc. but my understanding of Python just isn't sufficient to get anything to work without doing it in a very long winded way using a tangled mess of if then else statements that's probably going to tie me in knots!

What's the best way for me to do what I want?

Comment: Try `import time` and `time.sleep` for delays.

Comment: To split into chunks, the `chunks` function [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) should work.

Comment: @mgilson I vote to close as a duplicate, because the answer is the same

Comment: @mgilson @Marcin - this question is slightly different if you consider that when the input is a string, you can use the `re` module to chunk it with `re.findall('.{%d}' % length, string)`.

Comment: @carl.anderson -- sure you _could_.  I'm not convinced that it would be faster (although maybe ...) and it's definitely not easier to read to my un-re-trained eye.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

One solution would be to use this function:

```
def chunkstring(string, length):
    return (string[0+i:length+i] for i in range(0, len(string), length))
```

This function returns a generator, using a generator comprehension. The generator returns the string sliced, from 0 + a multiple of the length of the chunks, to the length of the chunks + a multiple of the length of the chunks.

You can iterate over the generator like a list, tuple or string - `for i in chunkstring(s,n):`
, or convert it into a list (for instance) with `list(generator)`. Generators are more memory efficient than lists because they generator their elements as they are needed, not all at once, however they lack certain features like indexing.

This generator also contains any smaller chunk at the end:

```
>>> list(chunkstring("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 5))
['abcde', 'fghij', 'klmno', 'pqrst', 'uvwxy', 'z']
```

Example usage:

```
text = """This is the first line.
           This is the second line.
           The line below is true.
           The line above is false.
           A short line.
           A very very very very very very very very very long line.
           A self-referential line.
           The last line.
        """

lines = (i.strip() for i in text.splitlines())

for line in lines:
    for chunk in chunkstring(line, 16):
        print(chunk)
```

Comment: I just about understand what the function is doing but I'm still missing some bits, such as how best to use the generated chunks.  For example I have "for line in file" followed by the code to update the display followed by a wait but how should I step through each chunk before moving onto the next line (i.e. how do I know how many chunks I have and refer to them e.g. if I use "for i in chunkstring(s,n):" how do I "print" chunk 1 or chunk 3?)

Comment: Never mind, I didn't understand your answer very well. I read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) explanation of iterables and generators which helped me realise my mistake.

Comment: I hadn't seen your edit. Thank you, that also clarifies it for me!

Comment: @LostRob That's unsuprising, I edited it in response to your comment!

Comment: Great snippet. And despite the name, there's nothing limiting it to strings.

Answer (score 12):

the standard library offers [textwrap.wrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap):

```py
from textwrap import wrap

s = "some random text that should be splitted into chunks"

print(wrap(s, width=3))

['som', 'e r', 'and', 'om ', 'tex', 't t', 'hat', 'sho', 'uld', 'be ', 'spl', 
 'itt', 'ed ', 'int', 'o c', 'hun', 'ks']
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution as it uses the standard library!

Comment: technicall, the other solutions also use only the standard lib. but I found this to be a very convenient wrapper (no pun intended ;-))

Answer (score 10):

My favorite way to solve this problem is with the `re` module.

```
import re

def chunkstring(string, length):
  return re.findall('.{%d}' % length, string)
```

One caveat here is that `re.findall` will not return a chunk that is *less than* the length value, so any remainder is skipped.

However, if you're parsing fixed-width data, this is a great way to do it.

For example, if I want to parse a block of text that I know is made up of 32 byte characters (like a header section) I find this very readable and see no need to generalize it into a separate function (as in `chunkstring`):

```
for header in re.findall('.{32}', header_data):
  ProcessHeader(header)
```

Comment: Nice. An incomplete final chunk can be included using `re.findall('.{1,%d}' % length, string)`.

Comment: More readable but 50% slower than regular slicing, from a few `timeit` runs I did.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an oldie, but like to add how to chop up a string with variable length columns:

```python
def chunkstring(string, lengths):
    return (string[pos:pos+length].strip()
            for idx,length in enumerate(lengths)
            for pos in [sum(map(int, lengths[:idx]))])

column_lengths = [10,19,13,11,7,7,15]
fields = list(chunkstring(line, column_lengths))
```

Answer (score 3):

Doing it with list-comprehension:

```
n = "aaabbbcccddd"
k = 3
[n[i:i+k] for i in range(0,len(n),k)]
=> ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this way is easier to read:

```
string = "when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."
length = 20
list_of_strings = []
for i in range(0, len(string), length):
    list_of_strings.append(string[i:length+i])
print(list_of_strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with ever more simplicity:

```
str_to_split="KIMJEONG" # Your string to split here
n=4 # Your chunk length here
buf=""
ourchunks=[]
x=0

for i in str_to_split:
   x += 1
   buf += i
   if (x % 4) == 0:
     ourchunks.append(buf)
     buf=""
```