# Dynamic border around text in python

Tags: python

I need to input a sentence and make a dynamic border around that sentence. The border needs to have a width that is inputted. When the length of the sentence is higher than the given width, a new line has to be printed and the border has to change in **height**. The sentence also has to be centered in the dynamic border

I already tried this:

```
sentence = input()
width = int(input())

length_of_sentence = len(sentence)

print('+-' + '-'*(width) + '-+')

for letter in sentence:
    print('| {0:^{1}} |'.format(letter, width - 4))

print('+-' + '-'*(width) + '-+')
```

but then each letter with a new line is printed and that's not what I need.

A great example is the following;

**Input**

```
sentence = "You are only young once, but you can stay immature indefinitely."
width = 26
```

**Output**

```
+----------------------------+
| You are only young once, b |
| ut you can stay immature i |
|         ndefinitely.       |
+----------------------------+
```

Comment: I know there are already posted questions around this topic but they don't cover dynamic inputs.

Comment: Take a look at [Split python string every nth character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-python-string-every-nth-character). That should get you started.

Comment: @DriesCoppens: So what? It shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So instead of doing a letter-wise input, you'd want to split the string into [chunks of `width` letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854620/whats-the-best-way-to-split-a-string-into-fixed-length-chunks-and-work-with-the). Taking the accepted answer:

```
def chunkstring(string, length):
    return (string[0+i:length+i] for i in range(0, len(string), length))

sentence = input('Sentence: ')
width = int(input('Width: '))

print('+-' + '-' * width + '-+')

for line in chunkstring(sentence, width):
    print('| {0:^{1}} |'.format(line, width))

print('+-' + '-'*(width) + '-+')
```

Example run:

```
Sentence: You are only young once, but you can stay immature indefinitely. 
Width: 26
+----------------------------+
| You are only young once, b |
| ut you can stay immature i |
|       ndefinitely.         |
+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but there is one problem I didn't mention. If the width is higher then the length of the sentence, the width is equal to the width of the sentence so you won't create a giant dynamic border.

Comment: Easy, just add there a line of `width = min(width, len(sentence))`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `textwrap.wrap` if you want to avoid breaking words in the middle:

```
from textwrap import wrap

sentence = input('Sentence: ')
width = int(input('Width: '))

print('+-' + '-' * width + '-+')

for line in wrap(sentence, width):
    print('| {0:^{1}} |'.format(line, width))

print('+-' + '-'*(width) + '-+')
```

Outputs:

```
+----------------------------+
|  You are only young once,  |
| but you can stay immature  |
|       indefinitely.        |
+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

i would use PrettyTable module for this task - it will take care of "nicely" printing:

```
import prettytable as pt

sentence = "You are only young once, but you can stay immature indefinitely."
width = 26


t = pt.PrettyTable()

t.field_names = ['output']
[t.add_row([sentence[i:i + width]]) for i in range(0, len(sentence), width)]

print(t)
```

Output:

```
+----------------------------+
|           output           |
+----------------------------+
| You are only young once, b |
| ut you can stay immature i |
|        ndefinitely.        |
+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

sentence = input()
width = int(input())

length_of_sentence = len(sentence)

print('+-' + '-'*(width) + '-+')

i = 0
lines = int(math.ceil(length_of_sentence/float(width)))
for l in xrange(lines): 
    line = sentence[i:i+width]
    if len(line) < width:
        padding = (width - len(line))/2
        line = padding*' ' + line + padding*' ' 
    print('| {0} |'.format(line))
    i += width

print('+-' + '-'*(width) + '-+')
```

Answer (score 0):

def chunkstring(string, length):
return (string[0+i:length+i] for i in range(0, len(string), length))

sentence = input('Sentence: ')
width = int(input('Width: '))

print('+-' + '-' * width + '-+')

for line in chunkstring(sentence, width):
print('| {0:^{1}} |'.format(line, width))

print('+-' + '-'*(width) + '-+')

Comment: Example run:

Sentence: You are only young once, but you can stay immature indefinitely. 
Width: 26
+----------------------------+
| You are only young once, b |
| ut you can stay immature i |
|       ndefinitely.         |
+----------------------------+