# Making frames around text

Tags: python

[I was trying to make a program that will put a frame made put of dashes & asterisk around any text entered in by the User, but encountered a syntax error trying to do so. I'm also trying to do it without using loops.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuylQ.jpg)

Comment: please put your code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please go through  here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  to see how you can ask a good question. For starters, you need to copy/paste your code in this post and not provide link.

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381065/dynamic-border-around-text-in-python. It answers your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic border around text in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35381065/dynamic-border-around-text-in-python)