# Pythonic composite for loop conditions

Tags: python

In C++/C, I can write the following:

```
string s;
int window_len = 3;
for (int i = 0, j = window_len; j <= s.length(); i += window_len, j += window_len) {
  //do things with s.Slice(i, j)
}
```

Is there a pythonic way of expressing the above composite for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to split a string into fixed length chunks and work with them in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854620/whats-the-best-way-to-split-a-string-into-fixed-length-chunks-and-work-with-the)

Comment: @DYZ That's pretty similar but not quite what I was looking for. chunkstring("abc", 2) returns "['ab', 'c']". The code above will return "['ab']"

Comment: You are right, there was an error in the snippet.

Comment: Just add an extra check to remove the last element if the string isn't divisible by the chunk length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that using the fact that floor dividing the length of the string by the "group"-size will truncate remaining characters:

```
>>> string = 'abcdefghijklm'
>>> size=2

>>> [string[i*size:(i+1)*size] for i in range(len(string) // size)]
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij', 'kl']
```

Or in a for-loop:

```
for i in range(len(string) // size):
    substr = string[i*size:(i+1)*size]
    # do stuff with substr
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this gets at the concept in a similar way and doesn't require a lot of additional math:

```
strides = range(0, len(s)+1, window_len)
for i, j in zip(strides, strides[1:]):
    # do something with s[i:j]
```

Comment: You need to use `len(s)+1` as stop in your `range` though. I was just about to post that one too but you were faster :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why, of course:

```
s = "Hello, world!"
[s[i:i + window_len] for i in range(0, len(s)-window_len+1, window_len)]
# ['Hel', 'lo,', ' wo', 'rld']
```

Comment: Same problem - the '!' shouldn't be there.

Comment: The solution before your edit worked. However, I would prefer something more intuitive at a glance - that's what I really liked about the C++ solution.

Comment: Should or should not? (It is.)

Comment: Sorry typo - shouldn't :D

Comment: No problem, let's take it out.

Comment: In fact, I started with this (corrected) solution, but them broke it because I thought you wanted the last incomplete chunk...