# How to make a program to detect consecutive letters in a QWERTY keyboard layout?

Tags: python

I know this was already asked by other person but i never understood the code and i guess this one is a bit different. So i need a code in my python program that removes 5 points from the variable "points". For example:  if password is qwert123 then there are 3 combinations "qwe", 'wer',"ert" and 15 points are removed.
Please help me, i need it in a simplest language as possible so i could understand it. Thank you a lot!

```
    user_password = input()
    password = int(len(user_password))
```

Comment: Have you tried anything else than the code shown above?

Comment: This question is too broad

Comment: Where's the link to the other persons question? What have you not understood about the answer there? Be specific, "give code" approach isn't helpful on SO. People will help you if you're willing to learn, if you just want the code, hire somebody to write this code for you.

Comment: I have not tried anything because i have no idea how to code it.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to this problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18854817/8888958).

Adapting it to the problem at hand, the following code will do what you require:

```
qwertyKeyboard = ['qwertyuiop', 'asdfghjkl', 'zxcvbnm']
user_password = input("enter password")
points = len(user_password)

def chunkstring(string):
    return (string[0+i:3+i] for i in range(0, len(string)))

for chunk in list(chunkstring(user_password)):
    if len(chunk) == 3:
        if chunk in qwertyKeyboard[0] or chunk in qwertyKeyboard[1] or chunk in qwertyKeyboard[2]:
            print(chunk)
            points -= 5

print(points)
```

The `chunkstring` function breaks the password up into chunks of characters, which are then checked by the `for` loop against the `qwertyKeyboard` list, and deducts 5 points from the `points` variable for each set three consecutive characters that are found.