# Seperating signs in string

Tags: python

I'd like to know how separate characters in string

i would expect something like that:

```
word = 'cool'
~~~~~~~~~~~~ - the code which i dunno
output :
c o o l
```

Comment: To separate: `print(*word)`

Comment: use list function `list("word")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since strings are iterables of characters, you can use the `join` method available on strings on strings too.

```
word = 'cool'
separated_word = ' '.join(word)
print(word)
print(separated_word)
```

outputs

```
cool
c o o l
```

And naturally you can also change the separator:

```
>>> print(' * '.join(word))
c * o * o * l
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which way you want to do it, if you want to split it into an array, have a look at this: [What's the best way to split a string into fixed length chunks and work with them in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854620/whats-the-best-way-to-split-a-string-into-fixed-length-chunks-and-work-with-the) and think of it as 'chunks of size 1'

if you just want to loop over and work on each char:

```
>>> my_str = "cool"
>>> for x in my_str:
...    print("->%s<-" % x)
... 
->c<-
->o<-
->o<-
->l<-
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
test = "cool"

output = ""
for l in test:
    output+=(l+" ")

print(output)
```