# How to break a 1000 digit long integer into mulitple lines in python

Tags: python, long-integer, pep8

For example I have 100 digit integer, which I want to break into multiple lines for better over view.

```
x = 1000000000
    0000000000
    0000000000
    0000000000
    0000000000
    0000000000
    0000000000
    0000000000
    0000000000
    0000000000
```

I tried breaking as per pep8, but it's showing invalid syntax error.

Comment: AFAIK you can't. Python does not allow number breaking. Also, you may want to rethink your design. Such huge constants will never be readable, regardless of line breaking.

Comment: This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character) can maybe help you

Comment: or you can define your own function like one in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854620/whats-the-best-way-to-split-a-string-into-fixed-length-chunks-and-work-with-the/18854817)

Comment: @freakish I am doing a problem in [https://projecteuler.net/](https://projecteuler.net/) where I have to work on 1000 digit integer, though I can split the integer in pieces using string. Writing in single line is hard to visualize.

Comment: You can use scientific notation as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913532/display-a-decimal-in-scientific-notation) ?

Comment: @AlexandreB. unfortunately you will loose precision when converting it to integer
`
>>>int(1e100)
10000000000000000159028911097599180468360808563945281389781327557747838772170381060813469985856815104
`

Comment: @AlexandreB. But I can't do that, since it does not have any zeros towards end. It is like 1234567890. I'll lose numbers if I user scientific notation

Comment: @JvdV I am not concerned with printing the number, rather breaking single line of long integer into multiple lines

Comment: @JvdV No, I asked this question to know if long integer can be split into multiple line when writing a code, so that I can visualize the number clearly

Answer (score 2):

You can use write big numbers like this:

`x = 10**n`  (`n` being the power)

Another form (reacting to your comment) is:

`x = 123
 x = x * (10**3) + 456`  (3 is a form of n)

Comment: My number is of the form 1234567890, not one followed by zeros

Comment: I added  that form to the answer

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is possible with integers, but you might use `/` to make multiline `str` representing number and then convert it to `int`, i.e.

```
x = '100\
000\
000'
x = int(x)
print(x)  # 100000000
print(type(x))  # <class 'int'>
```

*(tested in Python 3.7.3)*

This naturally means additional operation as opposed to explicit `x = 100000000`, however that conversion shouldn't be problem, unless your task is ultra-time-critical.

Regarding readibility note that if you use `Python 3.6` or newer you might use underscores in numeric literals as [PEP 515](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/) says. Speaking simply - you might place `_` in numeric literals as long as it is not adjacent to another `_` and not leading and not trailing character, so for example all following lines have same effect:

```
x = 1000
x = 1_000
x = 1_0_0_0
```

*and so on*

Answer (score 0):

Let:

```
x = 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

You could split it and view:

```
for i in [str(x)[i:i+10] for i in range(0,len(str(x)),10)]:
    print(i)
```

Gives:

```
1000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
```

As numbers can't be subscribed, we take the string of the number (x remains unaffected).
To store the output as a string ( as a view of x ):

```
view_of_x = '\n'.join([str(x)[i:i+10] for i in range(0,len(str(x)),10)])
```

Now print it:

```
print(view_of_x)
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing, but wonder if pep8 allows splitting integers into multiple lines

Comment: @147875 we split the str( your integer)