# pandas - convert a list into columns by modulo

Tags: python, pandas

I have a long list:

```
input_data = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, ...]
```

How can I to split them by their index number into:

```
  type1.  type2.  type3.  type4.
0.  a       b       c       d
1.  e       f       g       h
2.  ...
```

Comment: For the list case : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854620/whats-the-best-way-to-split-a-string-into-fixed-length-chunks-and-work-with-the#18854817

Comment: So the input is a list and the output is a df?

Comment: Btw don't override `input`.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `reshape`

```
n = 2#you can change to n = 4
out = pd.DataFrame(np.array(input).reshape((-1,n)))
Out[45]: 
   0  1
0  a  b
1  c  d
```